# "has nothing to do with" vs. "does not have anything to do with"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

What's the difference between "has nothing to do with" and "does not have anything to do with"?

For example:

> a) My question **has nothing to do with** homework.
>
> b) My question **does not have anything to do** with homework.

Comment: No, I did it intentionally because I wasn't aware it's a mistake. I'll edit it maybe.

Comment: I was just pointing out different variations, they were not your mistakes. Those are just the common usages.

Comment: And the common ways is exactly what I want and I need to know as ELL:) Thank you for this comment.

Comment: Right. I edited it. Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion pretty much the same. Maybe only a little bit different emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

If they mean anything, they mean the same thing, but it is difficult, perhaps impossible, to conceive of a situation in which either would be meaningful.

I think you are confusing them with a different idiomatic construction

> My question **has nothing to do** with homework.

or

> My question **does not have anything to do with** homework.

Both the immediately preceding sentences mean

> My question **does not concern** homework.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the idiomatic mistake in order to focus on the difference between these two. See the comments to my question.

Comment: By the way, the 1st sentence you wrote shouldn't be with the preposition 'with'? ("My question has nothing to do **with** homework").